# How get only the most recent input from System.in?

Tags: java, console

I'm implementing a console-based Tic Tac Toe game, using Java sockets. My implementation currently works well - that is, provided both parties play properly and wait their turn. The problem I'm having right now is that if one of the players input anything during the other player's turn, since I'm getting their input using Scanner#nextLine(), when it comes to be their own turn, it instantly switches back to the other person's turn and sends whatever the first thing they sent when it wasn't their turn to the server (if that makes any sense). This is obviously super undesirable. What I need is for all input a user submits out of turn to be discarded, and when it becomes their turn, the program should wait for a fresh input and use that instead.

To demonstrate the behaviour I'm referring to, here is a short code sample (not directly from my Tic Tac Toe for sake of simplicity, but similar concept):

```
Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

// Simulate other player's turn by sleeping for 5secs:
Thread.sleep(5000);
// Imagine player inputs things here, when they aren't supposed to...

System.out.println("Input: ");
// What I want is for the code to pause here and wait for input
//     no matter what, but instead, if you inputted something
//     while the thread was sleeping, it will print here.
System.out.println(r.nextLine());
```

Thanks!

Comment: Java isn't really suited to do complicated console things. The main reason is that it is very hard / not possible to do this in a cross-platform way.

Comment: I've also added an answer on the duplicate question with a way in which you could do it, but it's not simple and I wonder whether it is really worth the time to implement it in your case.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with sockets. Please don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks, Erwin. Utilizing a second thread was something I considered, but I was hoping perhaps there was some really simple solution to this I was overlooking. Guess I have my work cut out for me tonight!

Comment: @EJP Ah, yes, you're right of course. Thanks.